# Do a check before removing an entiry with preRemove

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an Entity Student that has Subjects with Assignments. Unfortunately the mappings are strange and I am not allowed to change that now, but the assignments know to which subject they belong, and the subjects know to which student they belong, and not the other way around. the student don't know its subjects, and its subjects don't know its assignments. Further more I do have onDelete=CASCADE" so by default the student will be deleted with its subjects with their assignments. And this works fine.

I want to create a check if the student has a subject with an open assignment the student can't be deleted, nor the subject.

If there are no open subject I want to remove the student, subject, and the assignment.

How can I perform this? I think I already have a backbone like this;

```
    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $student = $args->getEntity();

        if ($student instanceof Student) {
            $subjects = $em->getRepository(Subject::class)->findBy(['student' => $student]);

            foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
                if ($subject instanceof Subject) {
                    $assignments = $em->getRepository(Assignment::class)->findBy(['subject' => $subjects]);

                    foreach ($assignments as $assignment) {
                        if ($assignment->isCompleted()) {
                            echo $assignment." - CAN DELETE<br>";
                        } else {
                            echo $assignment." - CAN'T DELETE, THERE ARE OPEN ASSIGNMENTS!<br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What will now be the correct way to go? Just return true or false to stop or continue the operation? Or do I need to do specific Doctrine stuff again like remove etc. I'm not 100% sure what to do next.

I also need to create a custom exception if the assignments can't be deleted.

Can anybody please help? I'll appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a service and use it everytime I need to check this kind of operations. Sadly doctrine events and listeners are way too complex and, in a long time, will bring more problems that benefits. Of course if you do it "manually", you have to be sure to delegate that control everytime to that service and never delete those objects manually. Moreover having a service make your code less coupled to the ORM itself.

By the way looking at your code there's no "silver bullet answer" for this but I would prefer an `Exception` (of your custom type) that can be catched where you need to know that something wrong has happened